# ¿ Como cambiar el aspecto de mi barra de navegación?

Tags: html, css, entrada

Estoy tratando de hacer que el imput-type de la barra de navegación para buscar sea solo una imagen de lupa, y una vez pinchando, toda la barra de navegación se transforme en el input-text, cambiando también de color y ligeramente la altura de toda la barra.
Hasta ahora solo he conseguido lo que muestra mi código, en el cual ya me ayudaron (@Camilo Vasquez, @Pepo Gonzalez, @Alvaro Montoro), y revisando documentación de W3schools.
Si alguien me puede dar alguna idea para continuar construyendo mi web.
Gracias.

```css
/* LA VERDAD ES QUE FUNCIONA CASI TODO GRACIAS A LOS RETOQUES DE Camilo Vasquez, Alvaro Montoro*/
html, body {
    height:100%;
    margin:0px;
    color:#444444;
    -ms-text-size-adjust:100%;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;
    font:400 16px/1.8 sans-serif;
    }
    
    .nav-navbar-nav{
        font-size: 5;
    
    }
    .bgimg-1, .bgimg-2, .bgimg-3 {
    position:relative;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-position:center;
    background-size:cover;
    }
    .bgimg-1 {
    background-image:url("../imagenes/bg_01.jpg");
    height:100%;
    }
    .bgimg-2 {
    background-image:url("../imagenes/bg_02.jpg");
    height:100%;
    }
    .bgimg-3 {
    background-image:url("../imagenes/bg_03.jpg");
    height:100%;
    }
    .caption {
    position:absolute;
    left:10%;
    top:48%;
    width:80%;
    margin:auto;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    font-size:24px;
    text-align:center;
    letter-spacing:10px;
    background-color:#444444;
    }
    h2 {
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font:20px sans-serif;
    letter-spacing:4px;
    color:#444444;
    }
    a {
    text-decoration:none;
    letter-spacing:3px;
    }
    .navbar-nav{
      margin-left: 5% !important;
    }
    
    #center{
      padding-right:2%;
   }

    #header{
      position: fixed;
      width: 100%;
      z-index: 1000;
      font-size: 6
    }
    
    .navbar{
      margin-bottom: 0px !important;
    }

    .navbar ul li a{
      font-size: 12px
    }

    .col-md-6{
      padding-left: 5%;
    }

    .col-md-6{
      padding-right: 5%;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <title>PRINCIPAL</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

    <!-- ESTOS ENLACES LES TENGO GRACIAS A Camilo Vasquez me sugirio para crear barra de navegacion-->
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="css/todo.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style> 
        input[type=text] {
            width: 130px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            border: 2px solid #ccc;
            border-radius: 4px;
            font-size: 16px;
            background-color: white;
            background-image: url('#');
            background-position: 10px 10px; 
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            padding: 3px 20px 12px 40px;
            -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
            transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
        }
        
        input[type=text]:focus {
            width: 50%;
        }
        </style>
</head>
<!-- AQUI TAMBIEN FORMO PARTE Camilo Vasquez AYUDANDO ME CON LOS BOTONES DE LA BARRA DE NAVEGACION-->
<body>
    <header id="header">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
            <div class="container">
                <!-- Logo and responsive toggle -->
                <div class="navbar-header">

                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fire"></span>
                      MIGUEL ESPESO
                    </a>
                </div>
                <!-- Navbar links -->
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="active">
                            <a href="#">PRINCIPAL</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a target"_blank" href="Contacto.html">CONTACTO</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">TUTORIALES</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">SOBRE MI
                                <span class="caret"></span>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li>
                                    <a target="_blank" href="curriculum.html">CURRICULUM</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    
                                    <a target="_blank" href="proyectos.html">LOGROS</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Diseño</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- busqueda -->
                    <!--<form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Buscar</button>
                    </form>-->
                    <form>
                        <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Buscar...">
                      </form>

                </div>
                <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.container -->
        </nav>
    </header>

    <!-- AKI EMPIEZA ELCONDUMIO-->


    <div class="bgimg-1">
        <div class="caption">
            <span>CREAMOS LA APLICACION QUE NECESITE PARA SU NEGOCIO</span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div style="color:#444444;background-color:#FFFFFF;text-align:center;padding:48px 80px;text-align:justify;">
        <h2 style="text-align:center;">CURRICULUM</h2>
        <h1>BIENVENIDOS A MI SITIO WEB...</h1>
        <p>Hola, me llamo Miguel y os voy a presentar mi sitio web, el cual estoy creando mientras realizo un curso de actívate. 
         En principio esta creado para mostrar mi perfil, experiencia laboral, formación académica y todos los conocimientos que 
         vaya adquiriendo en el curso. </p>
    </div>

    <div class="bgimg-2">
        <div class="caption">
            <span>EMPEZANDO EN DESARROLLO WEB</span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div style="position:relative;">
        <div style="color:#FFFFFF;background-color:#444444;text-align:center;padding:48px 80px;text-align:justify;">
            <p>ESTO IRA MEJORANDOSE, SEGUN VAYA EXPERIMENTANDO</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="bgimg-3">
        <div class="caption">
            <span>MAS IMAGENES</span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div style="position:relative;">
        <div style="color:#444444;background-color:#FFFFFF;text-align:center;padding:48px 80px;text-align:justify;">
            <p>AQUI PONDRE IMAGENES, CUANDO VAYA APRENDIENDO</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="bgimg-1">
        <div class="caption">
            <span>¡DIVERTIDO, EH!</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

buenas amigo espero esto sea lo que buscas !!

Aqui te dejo el CodePen para que lo veas mejor saludos

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/lusaxweb/pen/LOBrPX)

```js
var activo = false
$("#buscar").click(function() {
  if (!activo) {
    $(this).parent("div").css({
      "width": "100%"
    });
    $(this).find("img").attr("src", "http://svgshare.com/i/44D.svg")

  } else {
    $(this).parent("div").css({
      "width": "40px"
    });
    $(this).find("img").attr("src", "http://svgshare.com/i/42h.svg")
  }
  activo = !activo
})
```

```css
/* LA VERDAD ES QUE FUNCIONA CASI TODO GRACIAS A LOS RETOQUES DE Camilo Vasquez, Alvaro Montoro*/


/*codigo nuevo*/

.buscar {
  position: absolute;
  width: 40px;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  right: 0px;
  transition: all .3s ease;
  z-index: 100;
}

.buscar input {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding:10px;
}

.buscar span {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  padding: 15px;
  background: rgb(245, 245, 245);
}

.buscar span img {
  width: 18px
}


/*codigo nuevo*/

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  color: #444444;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  font: 400 16px/1.8 sans-serif;
}

.nav-navbar-nav {
  font-size: 5;
}

.bgimg-1,
.bgimg-2,
.bgimg-3 {
  position: relative;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}

.bgimg-1 {
  background-image: url("../imagenes/bg_01.jpg");
  height: 100%;
}

.bgimg-2 {
  background-image: url("../imagenes/bg_02.jpg");
  height: 100%;
}

.bgimg-3 {
  background-image: url("../imagenes/bg_03.jpg");
  height: 100%;
}

.caption {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10%;
  top: 48%;
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 10px;
  background-color: #444444;
}

h2 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font: 20px sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  color: #444444;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}

.navbar-nav {
  margin-left: 5% !important;
}

#center {
  padding-right: 2%;
}

#header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
  font-size: 6
}

.navbar {
  margin-bottom: 0px !important;
}

.navbar ul li a {
  font-size: 12px
}

.col-md-6 {
  padding-left: 5%;
}

.col-md-6 {
  padding-right: 5%;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>PRINCIPAL</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

  <!-- ESTOS ENLACES LES TENGO GRACIAS A Camilo Vasquez me sugirio para crear barra de navegacion-->

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href="css/todo.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
  <style>
    input[type=text] {
      /*width: 130px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      border: 2px solid #ccc;
      border-radius: 4px;
      font-size: 16px;
      background-color: white;
      background-image: url('#');
      background-position: 10px 10px;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      padding: 10px;
      -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
      transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
    }
    
    input[type=text]:focus {
      width: 50%;
    }*/
  </style>
</head>
<!-- AQUI TAMBIEN FORMO PARTE Camilo Vasquez AYUDANDO ME CON LOS BOTONES DE LA BARRA DE NAVEGACION-->

<body>
  <header id="header">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
        <!-- Logo and responsive toggle -->
        <div class="navbar-header">

          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fire"></span> MIGUEL ESPESO
          </a>
          <!-- codigo Nuevo -->
          <div class="buscar">
            <span id="buscar"><img src="http://svgshare.com/i/42h.svg">            </span>
            <input placeholder="Buscar" type="text" name="" value="">
          </div>
          <!-- codigo Nuevo -->
        </div>
        <!-- Navbar links -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active">
              <a href="#">PRINCIPAL</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a target "_blank" href="Contacto.html">CONTACTO</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">TUTORIALES</a>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">SOBRE MI
                                <span class="caret"></span>
                            </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li>
                  <a target="_blank" href="curriculum.html">CURRICULUM</a>
                </li>
                <li>

                  <a target="_blank" href="proyectos.html">LOGROS</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Diseño</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <!-- busqueda -->
          <!--<form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Buscar</button>
                    </form>-->
          <form>
<!--             <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Buscar..."> -->
          </form>

        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </div>
      <!-- /

-->
    </nav>
  </header>

  <!-- AKI EMPIEZA ELCONDUMIO-->


  <div class="bgimg-1">
    <div class="caption">
      <span>CREAMOS LA APLICACION QUE NECESITE PARA SU NEGOCIO</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div style="color:#444444;background-color:#FFFFFF;text-align:center;padding:48px 80px;text-align:justify;">
    <h2 style="text-align:center;">CURRICULUM</h2>
    <h1>BIENVENIDOS A MI SITIO WEB...</h1>
    <p>Hola, me llamo Miguel y os voy a presentar mi sitio web, el cual estoy creando mientras realizo un curso de actívate. En principio esta creado para mostrar mi perfil, experiencia laboral, formación académica y todos los conocimientos que vaya adquiriendo
      en el curso. </p>
  </div>

  <div class="bgimg-2">
    <div class="caption">
      <span>EMPEZANDO EN DESARROLLO WEB</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div style="position:relative;">
    <div style="color:#FFFFFF;background-color:#444444;text-align:center;padding:48px 80px;text-align:justify;">
      <p>ESTO IRA MEJORANDOSE, SEGUN VAYA EXPERIMENTANDO</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="bgimg-3">
    <div class="caption">
      <span>MAS IMAGENES</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div style="position:relative;">
    <div style="color:#444444;background-color:#FFFFFF;text-align:center;padding:48px 80px;text-align:justify;">
      <p>AQUI PONDRE IMAGENES, CUANDO VAYA APRENDIENDO</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="bgimg-1">
    <div class="caption">
      <span>¡DIVERTIDO, EH!</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Gracias compañero por tu apoyo, eso es justo lo que quiero, pero no se porque cuando lo hago en pantalla grande no funciona. Y al poner en mi web tampoco.
Intentare resolver el problema por el cual no me funciona, pues cuando ejecuto tu código pantalla pequeña, si que funciona.
Gracias por la molestia.

Comment: Listo @MiguelEspeso ya lo acomode espero ahora si te funcione

Comment: Gracias compañero, ya estudiare como lo has echo, no me queda muy claro.

Comment: bueno no es tan complicado solo le agregue un `div` al menu que contiene un span y un input con javascript pongo el contenedor al 100% y al segundo click a 40 px que es el tamaño del boton inicial espero te ayude saludos